# Pcb trace width when connecting an ammeter and voltmeter together

Tags: pcb-design, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, trace

After design and simulate my 2 channel voltmeter/ammeter with arduino I came across with an issue about trace width.

This is an image with part of the circuit.

[image]

On +VL and GND I will connect the load to measure the current and in V+ and GND I will connect my dc-dc converter to measure it output voltage.

The orange traces you see going out of V+ connects V+ with a series of resistors that will act as a voltage divider, between other things too. (Ignore thin traces on sense resistor)

My question is for someone with experience. The orange traces should be more thicker (right now are 0.30mm) or are ok?, having in mind that V+ also connect to the sense resistor. (Voltmeter connects in parallel in a circuit so current is very low across it so this is why I choose 0.30mm width).

Comment: It depends what kind of currents are expected in the divider, and then estimating whether that current causes a significant or insignificant drop in the copper traces to have a significant or insignificant effect on the measurement.

Comment: I can’t make much sense of the layout. Use online track calculators to determine what width you should use for 5A. These will give a minimum value, so make the track thicker. If you’re concerned about voltage drop, then factor that into the info you get from the calculator.

Comment: my question refer for example If I connect a 5A load for also measure voltage, will the orange trace (used for voltmeter only) connected in V+ be enough? Red traces are also calculated for 5A already

Comment: How much current is flowing through the orange tracks? ‘Very low’ is not a number. You know your resistor values so you can calc the current. Given a track width you can estimate the effective resistance of the track. How does that compare with your divider resistances? At a guess, .3mm/12mil should be adequate, but we don’t know the whole story. Let the numbers answer your question.

Comment: That's a fairly point, I totally agree. Resistor total value is 41K and max voltage input is 20.5v so aprox 0.5ma will pass across the resistor. With 0.3mm I think it will be ok.